# Unable to run sample sales-force contact explorer application in Cordova project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

In visual studio 2015 When I try to run the sample sales-force contactexplorer application , I got the following error:

Here is my method:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
cordova.require("com.salesforce.util.logger").logToConsole("onDeviceReady:Cordova ready");
//Call getAuthCredentials to get the initial session credentials
cordova.require("com.salesforce.plugin.oauth").getAuthCredentials(salesforceSessionRefreshed, getAuthCredentialsError);
//register to receive notifications when autoRefreshOnForeground refreshes the sfdc session
document.addEventListener("salesforceSessionRefresh",salesforceSessionRefreshed,false);
//enable buttons
regLinkClickHandlers();
}
```

Here is my output:

jslog: onDeviceReady: Cordova ready

missing exec:com.salesforce.oauth.getAuthCredentials

TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAuthCredentials' of undefined(…)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAuthCredentials' of undefined
    at module.exports.exec 
    at exec (com.salesforce.util.exec.js:34)
    at Object.getAuthCredentials (com.salesforce.plugin.oauth.js:56)
    at onDeviceReady (index.html:64)
    at Channel.fire (cordova.js:820)
    at cordova.js:229
com.salesforce.oauth
getAuthCredentials

Comment: What version of Cordova are you targeting? According to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/hybrid_build_cordova3.htm, their sample apps require Cordova 3.6.3, which is very old, and Visual Studio will by default target the most recent version that it's compatible with.